# 70s(?) short story about a character who has visions of the eternal cycles of the time

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

It was about eternity and time... probably was a 70s short story. Maybe it was about the shapes that a soul could take along eons of time.

Sorry, I really cannot remember more. Just that it was a short story on an Italian collection book "Urania" and it was really mind-blowing.

Comment: You should really try to remember more about the story, because there are lots of stories about "eternity" and "time". How long ago did you read it? Do you think it was translated from English? Was there only one character?

Comment: probably was a 70s short story. Maybe it was about the shapes that a soul could take along eons of time.

Comment: If you think you might recognize it by title alone, you could take a look at http://www.isfdb.org - I found 81 titles including the word "Urania", and each has a list of the stories in it. Please do post (and accept) your own answer if you find it!

Comment: There is a list of all Urania magazines, with covers here. http://www.mondourania.com/
If you could  recognize the one you read then we might have more to go on.